# Data separate by date in php from MySQL using Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

This is from PhpMyadmin data:
[image]

and those are the code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Sn</th><th>Status</th> <th>Location</th> <th>Time</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_statustimeline WHERE cons_no = '$cons_no' ORDER BY date DESC";
        $results2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
        if($results2){
            while($row2 = $results2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $i++;
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='4'><?php echo $row2['date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2['status']; ?> - <?php echo $row2['Location']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2['address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2['time']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
          }
        }
    ?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

So I need those date like 2016-07-12, 2016-07-15, 2016-07-19 etc will Show separate with those information.

Comment: add in question how data do you want?

Comment: data will separate by date . and date will show every single row for every date. then other status will show other row by the time. You can check DHL tracking system how the show their status with this tracking number: 9699662545 
    http://www.dhl.com.bd/en/express/tracking.html
 than you will understand. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>Sn</th><th>Status</th> <th>Location</th> <th>Time</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
            $i=0;
            $cons_no=$row["cons_no"];
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_statustimeline WHERE cons_no = '$cons_no' ORDER BY date DESC";
            $results2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
            if($results2){
                $currentDate = false;
                while($row2 = $results2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $i++;
                    if ($row2['date'] != $currentDate){
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='4'><?php echo $row2['date']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $currentDate = $row2['date'];
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row2['status']; ?> - <?php echo $row2['Location']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row2['address']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row2['time']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
              }
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

My out put is like this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the same result as on DHL tracking system, you have 2 variants:

```
1) SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(date_column,time_column) DESC
```

and then in your script check if the date in the current row is different from the date in the previous row - this is the moment when you have to show your date separator;

```
2) SELECT DISTINCT date_column FROM table
```

you first collect all the dates you need with the above query, then for each of those dates you have to show a date separator and issue another SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column = Your_Currently_Enumerated_Date ORDER BY time_column DESC
```

to get the times and their status

Comment: Thanks IVO GELOV, I found my solution.

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you like to vote for it ? If it did not - okay, maybe next time :))))